# Gulp: I want to run same task concurrently with different argument to run some e2e test not in parallel mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, protractor

I run my e2e test suites with protractor in parallel mode and have created a gulp task to to run them and for purpose of running them parallel I try to keep all specs as independent as I could. However, there are some scenarios where I can not avoid global nature of feature and since I am running them parallel its breaking one of the spec and the only way to make sure that spec does not break intermittently is take that spec out of parallel suit and run it individually.

I use gulp.series to run all tasks concurrently but there is only task for that I pass argument, my question is "How can I run same task concurrently and pass different arguments from console?"

following is my structure:

> File : protractor.conf.js
>
> - suites: {
>
>   - suite1: "test/dir1/xyz.js",
>   - suite2: "test/**/*.js"
> - }
>
> File: package.json
>
> - "scripts": {
>
>   - "preprot": "webdriver-manager update",
>   - "prot": "gulp tests"
> - }
>
> File: gulpfile.js
>
> - function eetests(){
>
>   - --takes arguments
>   - returns
> - }
>
> gulp.task("tests", gulp.series(lint, styleCheck, eetests()));

and I tests with following command in terminal:

```
npm run prot --suite=suite2 --parallel= # of parallel browser instances
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
what I want to do is:

```
gulp.task("tests", gulp.series(lint, styleCheck, eetests(),eetests()));
```

and then pass may be two comments like

```
npm run prot --suite=suite2 --parallel= # of parallel browser instances
--suite=suite2 --parallel = 0
```

Also, Please advise me if there is another way to do this. My end goal is run whole suite in parallel mode except one or two specs, and run those one or to specs with one browser at a time.